# Spliting a list of strings in OCaml

Tags: string, list, ocaml

I have a list as `let a = ["q0,x";"q1,y"];` which is of type `string list`.

I want to make it as `[("q0","x");("q1","y")];` which is a list of `(string * string)` tuples.

How do I do that??

Answer (score 3):

You can use module [Str](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html) and the function `split` :

```
let split = 
   List.map (fun str ->
      match Str.split (Str.regexp ",") str with
        | a :: b :: _ -> a, b
        | _ -> assert false (* should not happen *))
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the List.map function? Then checkout the ocaml standard lib here: [link](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/index.html).
Basically, each element of the list will be split where "," is found and returned as a list, so "q0,x" will become [q0;x]. The pattern matching identifies the first and second elements and checks that the list has only 2 elements. When the pattern is matched, the tuple is returned

Comment: You should try to learn OCaml from the beginning. Check [ocaml-lang](http://ocaml-lang.org) you 'll find some links to really good tutorials.